# 'method group' cannot be made nullable

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I am working on a piece of code in C# which tries to get `Lines` from `financialRecords`:

```
IDictionary<string, List<Lines>> lines = financialRecords.Find(record => record.Operations.Where(operation => operation.Value is Creation) != null)?.Lines;
```

Then I do a check to see if the number of lines returned is greater than 0:

```
if (lines?.Count > 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

This piece of code performs with no issues.

However when I assign this to a dictionary, like so:

```
state.Metadata["Lines"] = financialRecords.Find(record => record.Operations.Where(operation => operation.Value is Creation) != null)?.Lines;

object lines = state.Metadata["Lines"];
```

When I do a check to see if the number of lines returned is greater than 0, I get an error:

```
CS8978: 'method group' cannot be made nullable.
```

It seems like the documentation for issue `CS8978` returns no matches when I look it up. Help on this or why it happens is appreciated!

Comment: Can you change `var` to the actual type so we can see you're really dealing with? Also, what is the type of `state.Metadata`?

Comment: @madreflection edited the above to reflect your comment. `state.Metadata` is of type `IDictionary <string, object> State<FinancialRecord>`